# How can i check if my string resource has a placeholder? Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, mobile

I have a list of string resources, i want to display them but i want to check for string res that have place holders in them, so that i can replace the placeholders with string values

```
<string name="app_name">Its a poem right?</string>
<string name="app_name">We are %1$s to the see the queen, are you %1$s</string>
<string name="app_name">where are we %s</string>
```

I want to be able to fill the place holders with this text in my fragment
var going = "goin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a string extension

```
fun String.containsPlaceholderRegex(): Boolean {
  val placeholderRegex = Regex("%([0-9]+\\$)?[a-zA-Z]")
  return placeholderRegex.containsMatchIn(this)
}
```

then you can check if the string has a placeholder by below.

```
stringPropertyName.containsPlaceholderRegex()
```

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK provides the ability to replace such placeholders out of the box as follows:

```
context.getString(R.string.your_resource, content1, ..., contentN)
```

Does it work for your use case, or you do have to do it manually for some reason?

Comment: In my usecase there is a list of these string resources and you have to iterate through the list to check for resources that have placeholders. Before then replacing the placeholder.